# Extract density function for distribution family

Tags: r

In R, how do I programmatically extract the probability density function for a given distribution family? For example, for the family `gaussian`, I would like the function `dnorm`, and for the family `poisson` I would like the function `dpois`.

Most of the "family" functions, such as `gaussian` and `poisson` return a nice structure with useful things like the link function, the inverse link function, and a function to calculate the AIC. The density function, unfortunately, is not available here.

If it helps, I also have access to the object returned by `glm` used with the family that I want to identify the probability density function.

Comment: There are 8 "family" functions documented at family. Just make a look-up map with the density function for each one. Don't spend lots of time programming something that doesn't need to scale when you can write a simple solution in < 5 minutes.

Comment: Indeed, my current solution is exactly that. The purpose of this question is to find if there is a more generalizeable way to do this, specifically for the case where users use external (non-base) packages fit GLMs.

Comment: If a user is using a non-base package with a non-standard link function, who knows if there even is a density function?